# Graphileon Proxy Feature issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, neo4j, graphileon

We are trying to use the Graphileon proxy feature, but everytime we are getting error as:

```
{"request":{"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/score/api","method":"POST","body":{"state":"*","bucket":[{"name":"Ram","tr1":"TR1","TC1":1}]}},"error":{"message":"Request `body` must be string or plain object(when `json`: true)","code":400},"code":400} with Status code 400
```

Here is the code we are using:

```
var schemaUrl =  "http://localhost:8080/score/api";
var body = JSON.stringify({
                    url: schemaUrl,
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: {
                            state : "*",
                            bucket:
                            [
                                {name: "Ram", tr1: "TR1", TC1: 1}
                            ]
                        }
                });
                
console.log("body == " + body);

$.ajax({
 url: "/proxy",  
          method: "POST",
          data: body
})
```

Can you please help what is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `body` must also be JSON so you need to do:

```
var body = JSON.stringify({
                    url: schemaUrl,
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                            state : "*",
                            bucket:
                            [
                                {name: "Ram", tr1: "TR1", TC1: 1}
                            ]
                        })
                });
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting - 415 (Unsupported Media Type)          [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported]                How can I set proper headers here?

Comment: Resolved it by using header from your previous post. Thank you so much again!